# Как сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки в Боте (telegram bot api на Python) выдавало разные сообщения в зависимости от времени

Tags: python, telebot

Никак не могу ни найти, ни придумать как реализовать, чтобы в боте при нажатии на кнопку send_message выдавал информацию в зависимости от времени.
Например

```
elif message.text == 'Кнопка':
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    kb1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка", url='сайт')
    kb.add(kb1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст', reply_markup=kb)
```

И вот где 'Текст' что бы при нажатии бот выдавал с 8:00 до 23:00 один текст 1, а с 00:00 до 8:00 другой текст2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
cur_time = int(time.strftime("%H"))
if cur_time >= 8 and cur_time <= 23:
    text = 'text1'
else:
    text = 'text2'
```

https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-time-python/funktsija-strftime-modulja-time/

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Вы мне очень помогли!